# How to aggregate DataFrame to count valus per ID in also with other columns in output Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, aggregate

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
ID  | COL1 | ... | COL_n
----|------|-----|-------
123 | P    | ... | ...
123 | P    | ... | ...
123 | M    | ... | ...
444 | BM   | ... | ...
567 | BM   | ... | ...
29  | P    | ... | ...
```

And I need to aggregate above columns so as to have output like below:

- How many time client bought P -> col: X_P
- How many time client bought M -> col: X_M
- How many time client bought in total M + P -> col: X_PM
- in my real dataset I have many more columns and I need to also have these columns in output

  | ID | COL1 | ... | COL_n | X_P | X_M | X_PM |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 123 | P | ... | ... | 2 | 1 | 3 |
  | 123 | P | ... | ... | 2 | 1 | 3 |
  | 123 | M | ... | ... | 2 | 1 | 3 |
  | 444 | BM | ... | ... | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 567 | BM | ... | ... | 0 | 0 | 0 |
  | 29 | P | ... | ... | 1 | 0 | 1 |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do two steps with  `pd.crosstab`

```
s = (pd.crosstab(df['ID'],df['COL1'])[['M','P']].
        assign(MP=lambda x : x.sum(1)).
        reindex(df['ID']).
        add_prefix('X_'))
s.index = df.index
df = df.join(s)
Out[178]: 
    ID COL1  X_M  X_P  X_MP
0  123    P    1    2     3
1  123    P    1    2     3
2  123    M    1    2     3
3  444   BM    0    0     0
4  567   BM    0    0     0
5   29    P    0    1     1
```